# Inserir na tabela se não existir

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Como inserir dados em uma tabela somente se não existir? a seguinte tentativa retorna um erro, a ideia basica é inserir um registro de modo **unico**,se já existir ignorar, caso contrario inserir o registro.

```
INSERT INTO registro_tb (nome, tag)
VALUES ('Darwin', '99649')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT nome FROM registro_tb WHERE nome='value'
);
```

alguma sugestão?

Comment: Fácil, ao criar a estrutura da tabela, indique que o campo em questão é `unique` desse modo se tentarem criar um registro com esse campo repetido, o próprio `mySql` retornará um erro de tentativa de quebra de integridade

Comment: uma coluna específica ou todas? dependendo do caso, `replace into` pode ser uma opção

Comment: Seria a combinação da linha, funcionaria como um _"Dictionary"_ .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690632/how-do-i-update-a-row-in-a-table-or-insert-it-if-it-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira mais simples que indico é adicionar ao campo *nome* uma **CONSTRAINT** de índice único. Ao tentar inserir uma nova entrada para o mesmo nome, o MySQL gerará um erro (que pode ser tratado pelo *chamador* do INSERT).

Para adicionar o constraint execute o código:

```
ALTER TABLE registro_tb ADD CONSTRAINT nome UNIQUE
```

**NOTA:** *Não podem existir registros com duplicidade no campo nome ao executar essa operação!*

Contudo, mesmo com o constraint único ativo, é possível dizer para o motor do MYSQL ignorar o erro de chave duplicada ao tentar a inserção:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO registro_tb (nome, tag)
VALUES ('Darwin', '99649')
```

Dessa forma será trivial inserir o registro no banco, sem se preocupar se ele já existe. Essa opção é também mais eficiente e rápida do que tentar verificar se o dado existe antes de inserir e é indicada para cenários com alto volume de dados.

Caso queira atualizar a entrada se ela já existir, pode-se usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO registro_tb (nome, tag)
VALUES ('Darwin', '99649')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag=VALUES(tag)
```

Nesse caso *nome* precisa ser uma primary key (até onde sei).

Comment: Meu velho, o caminho mais fácil e menos doloroso:
`ALTER TABLE registro_tb
ADD CONSTRAINT nome UNIQUE`

Comment: Detalhe que na base atual de dados não podem haver registros duplicados, se houver, não irá funcionar :)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio vou adicionar o código para adicionar o constraint à resposta, pois parece que o usuário que criou a pergunta talvez seja pouco experiente com banco de dados. Nem havia pensado em indicar como isso deve ser feito, pois é muito óbvio, e justamente não explicar o óbvio é que deixa os iniciantes perdidos :-)